# Hello how can i make this photos dynamic to every phone?

Tags: java, android, image

I am adding 3 photos every row and every row is in new costom view I just don't know how to make the photos to be dynamic for every phone like the size...

```
public void addImageToRaw(String path)
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(rawLinear1.getContext());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));

    rawLinear1.addView(imageView, 150, 150);
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screens width and height like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

From this you can set the margins.

Comment: why its matking in red this command: getWindowManager()
"cannot resolve method"

Comment: Your class needs to extend Activity or you need the context of the Activity.